# Please explain Apple's sprite kit example method in MyScence.m

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
   if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
```

My basic questions are 
1.) Where does the method get size from how is it imputed? 
  I know it suppose to be the size of the "screen" because it could be an iPhone or iPad.
2.)What is happening when self = [super initWithSize:size ] is executed ? 
    why is super calling initWithSize ? is that a recursive call to that method ? 
     And is super like calling self ? what is the difference ?

sorry for for my noob question, but no one really explains that they usually say you don't need to know about it, or assume you know about it. I have bought 1 book and watched how to videos.

Answer (score 2):

In the example, it's called from `ViewController.m`

```
SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
```

`super` isn't like calling `self`. If `ClassB` extends `ClassA` and both class implement a method `X`, then `[super X]` refers to the implementation in `ClassA` even if it's overridden by `ClassB`

In this case, `MyScene` extends `SKScene`. So in the `initWithSize` implementation of `MyScene`, calling `[super initWithSize:]` will make sure that the implementation in `SKScene` is also called (so it can initialize whatever it needs). Without it (i.e. is you called `[self initWithSize:]`) then it would wind up looping around and calling itself until the stack is full and you get an exception.

Based on the questions, I would strongly recommend you start with some simpler examples.

Comment: That really helped clear up my question. I think this is the simplest example i have found online.

Comment: Yeah, this is a more relevant answer than mine! +1

Answer (score 1):

The size will be input by the caller of the method... e.g.

```
Blah * myBlah = [[Blah alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(20.0f, 20.0f)];
```

Calling the super method means this class is inherited from another class ([See Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)) and the implementation of this initialiser requires the parent class (or superclass) to be initialised first.

Edit: Probably should state at this point, that almost all classes you ever make in Objective C are going to be subclasses of system classes, e.g. NSObject or UIView.